# How can I compare/search by java script values from html form in xml file?

Tags: javascript, html, ajax, xml

I am quite fresh to JS/AJAX and XML, however, I figured that I would play more with it and found myself a simple task.

I have created a simple HTML, JS and XML file for my small project. The project itself is quite simple. It is a SAPs, where a User can choose different types of food i.e. (Italian, Polish, Greek etc.) and also a User is able to choose what type of meal is being looked for i.e. (breakfast, dinner, supper, dessert etc.)

The HTML is just a front-end, the XML file stores all information about the "food" in such type

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
<?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl" href="dishes.xsl"?>
<Dish>
    <Food>
        <Id></Id>
        <Name></Name>
        <Type>/<Type>
        <Kind></>
        <Desc></Desc>
    </Food>
    <Food>
        <Id></Id>
        <Name></Name>
        <Type>/<Type>
        <Kind></>
        <Desc></Desc>
    </Food>
</Dish>
```

So far I was able to display all types of food and all types of meals on the HTML page in the table but I do not have a clue or any idea how can I create a simple "search" in xml file by using JS.

To be more specific I would to have such example working, when a User is on the web page, and chooses "Type of food" -> "Italian" && "Type of meal" -> "Dinner" then presses the "Search button". He/She gets a result table with all Italian dinner type meals.

If this is a duplicate or someone knows a close question, please refer me to it :)

Comment: Can you provide a bit more context? What does "SAPs" mean? What XML nodes do contain the information "Type of meal"? And btw, your XML is not well-formed.

Comment: SAP, Single Application Page and yes I  am aware that my XML might not be well formed because I am new in this matter, however I was able to solve the issue on my own. Thank for your interested still.